# Should we place C code in Static library or Runtime component?

Tags: windows-phone-8, runtime, components, static-libraries

We're moving to Windows Phone 8. But since many good libraries out there are in pure C. So what is the best way for Windows Phone C# application to consume this C library?

1. Place C code in WP Static library. Then reference it from WP Runtime
   component
2. Place C code in WP Runtime component

What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any real difference between the two approaches.  A static library is nothing but a collection of .obj files, the exact same kind of .obj files that you'll get from approach #2.  After the linker is done, there won't be any difference in the result.

That's when everything is perfect, an ideal that can be very difficult to achieve when you use open source C code.  An advantage of a static .lib is that it improves build time, not having to re-generate the .obj files.  But that's also their *disadvantage*, you'll shoot your foot if you use a .lib that was created by somebody else and he didn't use the same compiler version or compile options.  The simplest example of such a trap is building your Debug version and the .lib was built for Release.  Or if it uses winapi functions that are *verboten* in a Phone app, pretty common.  So #3 is the best way to avoid problems, build the .lib yourself so you can control all the compile and link settings.  Do beware however that it can be very difficult to get open source C code to build, it often comes with a very extensive configuration script, designed to deal with the differences between the many architecture and Unix variants.